# How to remove the default shadow of QPushButton?

Tags: pyqt

How to remove the shadow indicated by the arrow below?

[image]

I searched for some solutions and I didn't find a good answer.

Comment: That doesn't seem a standard Qt button. If you're using a stylesheet, please provide it. If you're on Linux, specify the distribution you're using.

Comment: yes I use some stylelsheet but I didn't use shadow ?

Comment: That's not a shadow, it's a border. As said, please provide the stylesheet you're using by editing your post.

Comment: QPushButton{
 color: #ffffff;
 background-color: #EA382A;
    box-shadow: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.01)
}

QPushButton:hover{
 color: #EA382A;
 background-color: #ffffff;
}
QPushButton:pressed{

 color: #ffffff;
 background-color: #EA382A;
}

Comment: Please don't put code in comments, they're not intended for that. Edit the post ensuring that you're correctly [formatting the code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362).

Comment: Also, for future reference, try to be more clear in your questions and always consider if a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) should be included, like in this case. If you had specified that you were using a stylesheet and included it right from the beginning, you'd have avoided wasting time and useless comments. As soon as you'll edit the post with the code, I'll provide a possible answer.

Comment: ok I will do. and I didn't set the border to None in the stylesheet. and I solved my problem. thanks a lot for this note.  @musicamante

Comment: if you found the solution on your own, then you should be able to provide an answer yourself (I'm not completely sure you can, though, as you have a very low reputation; consider the above suggestions and learn more about [asking good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), which can get upvotes instead of downvotes, and, then, higher reputation). Also remove the `box-shadow` attribute, as it will be completely ignored (Qt stylesheets are only a partial implementation of CSS 2.1, which didn't include such a feature anyway).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

by setting border to "**transparent**" you'll get the result as pictured below

```
QPushButton{
  background-color: rgb(234, 56, 42);
  color:white;
  border:transparent;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Just set the border to `none`:

```css
QPushButton {
    color: #ffffff; 
    background-color: #EA382A; 
    border: none; 
}

QPushButton:hover {
    color: #EA382A; 
    background-color: #ffffff; 
}

QPushButton:pressed {
    color: #ffffff; 
    background-color: #EA382A; 
}
```

Comment: Note: I edited your answer to remove the box-shadow: leaving it may lead others to believe that it works (while it doesn't, since it's not implemented).